# Clean up sha256sum output

Tags: linux, shell-script

running `sha256sum` folder/file` returns

```
711ad4b9939e0e20e591d753103717f40e794babc4129a0670fd342309bec5af *folder/file
```

I want to output the sum with just the filename next to it so that it looks like:

```
711ad4b9939e0e20e591d753103717f40e794babc4129a0670fd342309bec5af file
```

How do I go about changing the output?

Comment: `sed` is your friend - you'll have to get somebody else to tell you how to use it ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try

```
sha256sum /path/to/file | head -c 64
```

This is for taking only the hash of 64 characters.
As there were mentioned before, you should read the **man** of **sed** for more advanced manipulation.

But to have the output that you want, I mean without folders, a simple way is running the command from the folder where the file is located ;)

In your case:

```
cd folder/ ; sha256sum file
```

Comment: To get the first part before the space, regardless of it's length (not just 64), yes, sed can be used, or cut, or awk... I personally find cut most readable.  

sha256sum /path/to/file | sed 's/ .*//'
OR
sha256sum /path/to/file | cut -d' '  -f1
OR
sha256sum /path/to/file | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
sha256sum folder/file | sed 's, .*/, ,'
```

should do the job. I didn't test it though.

Comment: tested it and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't run sha256sum folder/file then.  Change to the directory first:

```
( cd folder && sha256sum file )
```